# Efficient algorithm for finding the intersection of repeated subdivisions of a list of elements

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization, set

*Edit for clarity:* I'm looking for the most efficient (and preferably elegant) way in C# to find the n-wise intersection of various subdivisions of the same set. Details below.

---

1. I have a list of elements. For simplicity, imagine it to be the integers 1-100.
2. This list has been divided into multiple groups such that all elements exists in exactly one group. E.g. **Division 1**

   - **Group 1:** 1,5-8,52-73
   - **Group 2:** 2-4,38-51
   - **Group 3:** 9-37,84-100
   - **Group 4:** 74-83
3. Step #2 has been repeated a number of times (i.e. there are a number of distinct divisions of this list). E.g. **Division 2**

   - **Group 1:** 1-27,59-80,99-100
   - **Group 2:** 28-31,81-98
   - **Group 3:** 32-58
4. I want to 'merge' (there's probably a better term for this) these divisions such that if any two elements are separate in any of the divisions, they are separated in the final result. Phrased differently: only those elements that are together in all divisions are together in the final result. E.g. for the above two divisions *(D = division, G = group)*:

   - **Group 1** *(D1G1 x D2G2)*: 1,5-8,59-73
   - **Group 2** *(D1G1 x D2G3)*: 52-58
   - **Group 3** *(D1G2 x D2G1)*: 2-4
   - **Group 4** *(D1G2 x D2G3)*: 38-51
   - **Group 5** *(D1G3 x D2G1)*: 9-27,99-100
   - **Group 6** *(D1G3 x D2G2)*: 28-31,84-98
   - **Group 7** *(D1G3 x D2G3)*: 32-37
   - **Group 8** *(D1G4 x D2G1)*: 74-80
   - **Group 9** *(D1G4 x D2G2)*: 81-83

I don't care about the order of groups in the final result. I'm just looking for the most efficient and cleanest solution.

At present the only way I can think to do this is:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> MergeDivisions(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>> divisions)
{
    var currentMerge = divisions.First();
    foreach (var division in divisions.Skip(1))
    {
        var nextMerge = new List<List<int>>();
        foreach (var currentMergeGroup in currentMerge)
        {
            foreach (var group in division)
            {
                var nextMergeGroup = currentMergeGroup.Intersect(group);
                if (nextMergeGroup.Any())
                    nextMerge.Add(nextMergeGroup.ToList());
            }
        }
        currentMerge = nextMerge;
    }
    return currentMerge;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what's your need but by looking at your code, it seems that you have a tree of some sort, maybe you can use a tree structure and traverse it and act accordingly, i.e. each node can be specialized.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If I am right, you are just trying to produce the pairwise intersections of the groups**, where a group can be described as a list of intervals `[b,e)`*. I assume that the intervals are sorted left-to-right. As all intervals are described by two bounds, you can use a flat list.

E.g.

```
{1, 2, 5, 9, 52, 74} ∩ {28, 32, 71, 99}
```

Now imagine a standard list merging process (as in Mergesort), which would result in

```
{1, 2, 5, 9, 28, 32, 52, 71, 74, 99}
```

For every bound in this list, you can tell exactly which intervals contain it and the following elements.

```
{1, 2, 5, 9, 28, 32, 52, 71, 74, 99}
 1  -  1  -  1   -   1   3   2   -
```

(`3` means `1+2`).

Now it is an easy matter to see that the elements in both groups are `[71, 74)`, and those in only the first are `[1, 2)`, `[5, 9)`, `[28, 32)`, `[52, 71)`.

*It is more convenient to use the last index plus one.

**I am not sure I understood how you define that merging, but I guess the above technique can be useful.

Comment: (1/2) Thanks for your response. Yes, you are correct that I am looking for the intersection of groups, but rather than 'pairwise' per se, more n-wise. For example, if I have the set of integers [1,10] and it has been subdivided into groups three times:
`D1G1: [1,5], D1G2: [6,10]
D2G1: [1,3], D2G2: [4,10]
D3G1: [1,7], D3G2: [8,10]`

Comment: (2/2) I'm looking for an efficient (fast) way to do `D1G1 ∩ D2G1 ∩ D3G1, D1G1 ∩ D2G1 ∩ D3G2, ... , D1G2 ∩ D2G2 ∩ D3G2`. Or more generalised `D1 G1 ∩ ... ∩ Dm G1, ... , D1 Gn_1 ∩ ... ∩ Dm Gn_m`. The above would result in:
`D1G1 ∩ D2G1 ∩ D3G1: [1,3]
D1G1 ∩ D2G1 ∩ D3G2: 
D1G1 ∩ D2G2 ∩ D3G1: [4,5]
D1G1 ∩ D2G2 ∩ D3G2: 
D1G2 ∩ D2G1 ∩ D3G1: 
D1G2 ∩ D2G1 ∩ D3G2: 
D1G2 ∩ D2G2 ∩ D3G1: [6,7]
D1G2 ∩ D2G2 ∩ D3G2: [8,10]`